# How do I append an item to an array in a pipeline?

Tags: bash, pipe, array

This script should simply add a value to an array through a loop and then show all items of an array.

```
#!/bin/bash

data_file="$1"
down=()
counter=0

cat $data_file | while read line; do \
    isEven=$(( $counter % 2 ))
    if [ $isEven -eq 0 ]; then
        down+=("$line")
    fi
    (( counter ++ ))
done

echo ${down[@]}   
exit
```

But all I see is empty string:

```
host@user$ sh script.sh data_file

host@user$
```

The `data_file` contains this:

```
81.11
11.63
81.11
11.63
81.11
11.63
81.11
11.63
```

Where's my mistake? Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot refer variable updates made in the child process (pipe connected while block).

Instead, feed data using input redirection like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

data_file="$1"
down=()
counter=0

while read line; do
    isEven=$(( $counter % 2 ))
    if [ $isEven -eq 0 ]; then
        down+=("$line")
    fi
    (( counter ++ ))
done < $data_file

echo ${down[@]}   
exit
```